# Jupyterhub multiple sessions per tab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I am new to Jupyterhub and have been tasked to find out the following.

Our team has picked up that multiple sessions are created when new tabs are open.

Is there a way to ensure that only one session is used even when the IDE is open in multiple tabs?